# Two topological groups $\mathrm{O}(n)$ (orthogonal group) and $\mathrm{SO}(n)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-isomorphism

**Problem.** *(Basic topology (M.A.Armstrong) Exercise 16 in chapter 4.3)*

(1) Prove that $\mathrm{O}(n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(n)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. (2) Are these two isomorphic as topological groups?

($\mathrm{O}(n)$ : [Orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group), $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ : Special orthogonal group)

---

**My attempt for (1) :**

Let's pick any element $C$ from $\mathrm{O}(n)-\mathrm{SO}(n)$, and let

\begin{aligned}
&f:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to \mathrm{SO}(n) ; \; f(A)=A\\
&g:\mathrm{O}(n)-\mathrm{SO}(n)\to \mathrm{SO}(n) ; \; g(A)= CA
\end{aligned}

Then $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms. Since $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is compact, $g^{-1} (\mathrm{SO}(n))=\mathrm{O}(n)-\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is also compact. So, they are closed in the subspace topology on $\mathrm{O}(n)$. Thus, by the glueing lemma, the function
$$\varphi:\mathrm{O}(n)\to \mathrm{SO}(n)\times \mathbb{Z}_2; \; \varphi(A)=
\begin{cases}
(f(A), 0)\quad&(\text{when }A\in \mathrm{SO}(n))\\
(g(A), 1)&(\text{otherwise})
\end{cases}$$
becomes continuous. We can easily confirm that $\varphi$ is bijective and $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

**Questions :**

**(1)** I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction (in proving (1)). I used glueing lemma to justifying continuousness of the function $\varphi$, but I doubt whether I'm using that lemma in the right place.

**(2)** 
I tried to prove that two groups are NOT isomorphic, but I can't find any key for that. I tried to compare orders of elements in two groups, but I couldn't find some good elements to compare... Is there any simple way to check whether two groups are isomorphic?

Thanks.

Comment: Think about the centers of the two groups. The answer, if I'm right, depends on $n$.

Comment: Mike Miller // Thanks. I'll think about them.

Comment: OP I hope your question hasn't been closed as I don't think your question(1) has an answer in the aforementioned link. Yes the map you have constructed is a homeomorphism and you use the gluing lemma in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the mapping $f:O(n)→SO(n)×Z_22$ given by
$M→(det(M)⋅M,detM)$

I think your answer is not right. Check det [det(M)M]= [det(M)]^{n+1}. Thus if $n$ is even, it will be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Consider the mapping $f: O(n)\to SO(n)\times \Bbb{Z}_2$ given by $$K \to \{\text{det}(M)\cdot M,\text{det}M\}$$ This is a well defined one to one and onto map. You can check that the map above is continuous.

Now since we know that $O(n)$ is compact and $SO(n)\times \Bbb{Z}_2$ is Hausdorff , the following map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The map is not even well-defined when n is even as @NguyenDangSon said.