# Are $SO(n)\times Z_2$ and $O(n)$ isomorphic as topological groups?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I am doing Exercise 4-16 in Armstrong's Basic Topology. The question is : are $SO(n)\times Z_2$ and $O(n)$ isomorphic as topological groups? (I have proved the homeomorphic part).

The problem is, I can prove that the map I constructed is merely a homeomorphism but not an isomorphism, but I cannot prove that there exists no isomorphism.

I am aware of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468198/two-topological-groups-mathrmon-orthogonal-group-and-mathrmson-ti), where an answer says to consider the map
$O(n)\to SO(n)\times Z_2,\ M\mapsto(M\det M,-1)$. But this is not well defined if $n$ is even. For example, when $n=2$, $\left(\matrix{1&0\\0&-1}\right)$ is mapped to $\left(\matrix{-1&0\\0&1}\right)$, which does not lie in $SO(2)$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes when $n$ is odd. No when $n$ is even.

When $n$ is odd $\{\pm I\}$ is a complementary subgroup to $SO(n)$
in $O(n)$.

But when $n$ is even, the centre of
 $O(n)$ consists of $\pm I$ which are both in $SO(n)$. But in $SO(n)\times Z_2$
there is a central element not in $SO(n)$.

Comment: For $n$ even, you implicitly use that an isomorphism $O(n)\to SO(n)\times Z/2$ should map $SO(n)$ onto $SO(n)$. This is true for $n\neq 2$ since then $SO(n)$ is the derived subgroup at both sides. For $n=2$ however one can directly argue that $O(2)$ is non-abelian while the product group is abelian. Or alternatively restate the argument (for arbitrary positive even $n$) saying that in $O(n)$ the center is contained in the derived subgroup, and not in $SO(n)\times Z/2$.