# Are $O(n)$ and $SO(n)\times Z_2$ homeomorphic as topological spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I'm working through Problem 4.16 in Armstrong's *Basic Topology*, which has the following questions:

> 1. Prove that $O(n)$ is homeomorphic to $SO(n) \times Z_2$.
> 2. Are these two isomorphic as topological groups?

**Some preliminaries:**

Let $\mathbb{M_n}$ denote the set of  $n\times n$ matrices with real entries. We identify each matrix $A=(a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{M_n}$ with the corresponding point $(a_{11},a_{12},...,a_{1n},a_{21},a_{22}...,a_{2n},...,a_{n1},a_{n2},...,a_{nn}) \in \mathbb{E}^{n^2}$, thus giving $\mathbb{M_n}$ the subspace topology.

The *orthogonal group* $O(n)$ denotes the group of orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices $A \in \mathbb{M_n}$, i.e. with $det(A)=\pm{1}$.

The *special orthogonal group* $SO(n)$ denotes the subgroup of $O(n)$ with $det(A)=1$.

$Z_2=\{-1, 1\}$ denotes the multiplicative group of order 2.

**My attempt**

For odd $n$, the answer to both questions is **yes**, as we verify below. Consider the mapping
$f:O(n)\to SO(n)\times Z_2, A \mapsto(det(A)\cdot A, det(A))$.

We have the following facts about $f$:

- **It is injective.** If $f(A)=f(B)$ then $(det(A)\cdot A, det(A))=(det(B)\cdot B, det(B))$.
  Therefore, $det(A)=det(B) \neq 0$ so $A=B$.
- **It is surjective.** For $(D,d) \in SO(n) \times Z_2$, we can take $dD \in O(n)$,
  giving $f(dD)=(det(dD)\cdot dD, det(dD))=(d^n\cdot det(D) \cdot dD,d^n \cdot det(D))=(d^{n+1}D, d^n)=(D,d)$, since $n$ is odd.
- **It is a homomorphism.** $f(AB)=(det(AB)\cdot AB, det(AB))=(det(A)det(B)\cdot AB, det(A)det(B))$
  $=((det(A)\cdot A)(det(B)\cdot B), det(A)det(B))=f(A)f(B)$.
- **It is continuous.** Let $\mathcal{O} \in SO(n) \times Z_2$ be open. Then $\mathcal{O}=U \times V$ for $U$ open in $SO(n)$ and $V$ open in $Z_2$.
  Since $SO(n)$ is open in $O(n)$, $U$ is therefore open in $O(n)$. $-U=\{-A\mid A\in U\}$ is also open in $O(n)$. But $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})=f^{-1}(U\times V)=U\cup -U$.

Since $O(n)$ is compact and $SO(n)\times Z_2$ is Hausdorff, we therefore have that $f$ is a homeomorphism. Thus, they are isomorphic as topological groups.

---

For even $n$, this mapping is not well-defined: if $A \in O(n)$ with $det(A)=-1$ then, $det(det(A)\cdot A)=(det(A))^{n+1}=-1$, so $det(A)\cdot A \notin SO(n)$.

My question then is **are they homeomorphic as topological spaces if $n$ is even?**

From the related questions, it seems like for even $n$, the two groups cannot be isomorphic due to <s>one being abelian while the other is not and</s> them having different centers and derived subgroups (I don't fully understand these arguments but I will brush up on them). So they cannot be isomorphic as topological groups. But can they be homeomorphic as topological spaces?

---

Related questions:

[Are $SO(n)\times Z_2$ and $O(n)$ isomorphic as topological groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399888/are-son-times-z-2-and-on-isomorphic-as-topological-groups)

[Two topological groups $\mathrm{O}(n)$ (orthogonal group) and $\mathrm{SO}(n)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468198/two-topological-groups-mathrmon-orthogonal-group-and-mathrmson-ti?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[understanding $O(n)$ homeomorphic to $SO(n)\times \Bbb Z_2$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537037/understanding-on-homeomorphic-to-son-times-bbb-z-2-proof)

[Why is the orthogonal group $\operatorname{O}(2n,\mathbb R)$ not the direct product of $\operatorname{SO}(2n, \mathbb R)$ and $\mathbb Z_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29279/why-is-the-orthogonal-group-operatornameo2n-mathbb-r-not-the-direct-prod)

Comment: Neither $O(n)$ nor $SO(n)$ is abelian.

Comment: @BenSteffan ah, sorry. You're right. I was thinking of the case when $n=2$. I'll add an edit to note this.

Comment: Hint: Prove that $O(n)$ has two homeomorphic connected components.

Comment: Being pedantic, note that $O(0) = SO(0)$. But other than that, yes, $O(n)$ is a disjoint union of two copies of $SO(n)$ like Moishe Kohan points at in the hint.

Comment: @MoisheKohan We can show that $O(n)$ must have **at least** two components since $det: \mathbb{M_n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. If $O(n)$ were connected, then its image $det(O(n)=\{-1,1\}$ would be connected, which is not the case. One of its components is $SO(n)$ and the other one is $O(n) - SO(n)$. Thus, $O(n)$ looks like two copies of $SO(n)$. I'm not sure of a simple way to show that there are **exactly** two components, though.

Comment: Well, $SO(n)$ [is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711492/prove-that-the-manifold-son-is-connected). More importantly, both copies of $SO(n)$ in $O(n)$ are open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $\varphi\colon SO(n) \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \to O(n)$, $\varphi(M, s) = I_s M$ where $I_0 = \mathrm{Id}_n$ is the identity matrix and $I_1 = \operatorname{diag}(-1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ is the diagonal matrix with a $-1$ as the first entry and all other diagonal entries equal to 1. Clearly $I_s \in O(n)$ for both $s = 0$ and $s = 1$, so the map is well-defined and evidently continuous. Since the image of $SO(n) \times \{0\}$ under $\varphi$ consists exclusively of matrices with determinant 1 and that of $SO(n) \times \{1\}$ exclusively of matrices of determinant $-1$, the map is injective (since on each component it is just given by multiplication with a group element), and surjectivity is also not difficult to see: If $M \in O(n)$ has $\det(M) = -1$, then $\det(I_1 M) = 1$ and consequently $I_1 M \in SO(n$), whence $M = \varphi(I_1 M)$ lies in the image. Thus, we conclude (by the compact-Hausdorff lemma) that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
\mathrm{O}(n) = \{A \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb R): A^\intercal A = I_n\}, \quad C_2 = \{\pm 1\}
$$
be, respectively, the orthogonal group and the group with two elements. Since $\det\colon \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$,  is multiplicative and $\det(A^\intercal) = \det(A)$, if $A \in \mathrm{O}(n)$ then $1=\det(A^\intercal)\det(A) = \det(A)^2$, so that $\det(A)\in C_2$. Moreover, if $s\colon C_2\to \mathrm{O}(n)$ is given by $s(\epsilon) = \mathrm{diag}(\epsilon,1,\ldots,1)$, then $s$ is a group homomorphism and $\det(s(\epsilon))=\epsilon$. Since by definition $\mathrm{SO}(n):=\det_{|\mathrm{O}(n)}^{-1}(\{1\})$ it follows that $\mathrm{O}(n)= \mathrm{SO}(n).H$ where $H = s(C_2)$.

An internal product like this can also be described as a *semi-direct product*. In this case, as a set the semidirect product is $\mathrm{SO}(n)\times C_2$, but the group operation is not simply componentwise, rather it is twisted by an action of $C_2$ by automorphisms on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$: for a pair of elements  $(g_1,\epsilon_1),(g_2,\epsilon_2) \in \mathrm{SO}(n)\rtimes C_2$ their product is defined to be
$$
(g_1,\epsilon_1).(g_2,\epsilon_2) = (g_1 s(\epsilon_1) g_2 s(\epsilon_1)^{-1}, \epsilon_1\epsilon_2), 
$$
or, if we write $c_g(h) = ghg^{-1}$ for $g,h \in \mathrm{SO}(n)$, then  $(g_1,\epsilon_1).(g_2,\epsilon_2) = (g_1c_{s(\epsilon_1)}(g_2), \epsilon_1\epsilon_2)$. The fact that $\mathrm{O}(n) = \mathrm{SO}(n)\times H$ can then be rephrased as saying that the map

$$
m \colon \mathrm{SO}(n) \rtimes C_2 \to \mathrm{O}(n), \quad m(g,\epsilon) = g.s(\epsilon), (\forall g \in \mathrm{SO}(n), \epsilon \in C_2),
$$
is an isomorphism of groups.

We may view $C_2$ as a topological group by equipping it with the discrete topology (so that any subset of $C_2$ is open in $C_2$) so that $\mathrm{SO}(n)\rtimes C_2$ is a product of topological groups and hence a topological group itself. Thus it makes sense to ask if $m$ is also homeomorphism.

Now since $\det$ is continuous and the image of $\det_{|\mathrm{O}(n)}$ is the discrete set $\{1,-1\}$, it follows that $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(n).s(-1)$ are both open in $\mathrm{O}(n)$. Now if $g \in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ then $m^{-1}(g) = (g,+1)$, which is clearly continuous since its components $g \mapsto g$ and $g\mapsto 1$ are, and similarly if $g\in \mathrm{SO}(n)s(-1)$, then $m^{-1}(g) = (gs(-1),-1)$ so that the restriction of $m^{-1}$ to any coset of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ in $\mathrm{O}(n)$ is continuous. Since these cosets form an open cover of $\mathrm{O}(n)$, it follows that $m^{-1}$ is continuous, and hence $m$ is an isomorphism of topological groups, *i.e.* an isomorphism which is also a homeomorphism.

Comment: This is a good reminder that I need to brush up on my algebra. I can understand everything clearly until the part about the cosets and the semidirect product; I'm having difficulty understanding how that gives a homeomorphism. Also, should that be $\epsilon$ instead of $f\epsilon$? Also, can you give some hints to show that $phi$ is a homomorpism? I'm guessing it'll boil down to matrix multiplication being associative?

Comment: The cosets are $s(+1).\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and $s(-1).\mathrm{SO}(n)$ (the first just being $\mathrm{SO}(n)$). Since the group operation is continuous, the map $g \mapsto h.g$ is homeomorphism, and hence $s(-1).\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is open and closed because $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is.) I've also corrected some wayward notation in my original answer, which I hope will clarify and avoid most of the confusions